# Is there a way to create a NamedStyle from a cell in python?

Tags: python, excel, formatting, openpyxl

This seems like a basic issue, But I can't find anything on the internet.

I want to create a style template/NamedStyle based on a cell in excel in python.
I wanted to basically copy all the formatting style of a cell and store it and then use it as needed.

Example :

```
A=NamedStyle(name="OFF")     #Creating a NamedStyle
```

Later on,Something like this :

```
A=NamedStyle(cell_obj.style)  #Importing the style of an existing cell into the NamedStyle
```

And then later on,

```
cell_obj.style=A             #Applying NamedStyle to a cell
```

I'm getting a `"TypeError: 'Cell' object does not support item assignment" for A=NamedStyle(cell_obj.style)`

I understand that this syntax might be wrong, But what is the right syntax? All I can find on the internet is creating of NamedStyle and personally editing the attributes and then using it.
I want to basically import the styles of an existing cell of an excel into a NamedStyle so that i can reuse this in a different excel in a future point of time. How do I do this?

Regards,
Vivek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do something like this?
The existing cell 'B2' a has style applied, font, border, alignment, fill, date format. These are copied into a style called 'namedstyle'.
The raw value is entered into cell 'B4' and the 'namedstyle' applied.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle, 
from copy import copy


wb = load_workbook("foo.xlsx")
ws = wb['Sheet1']

### Select cell to copy from
style_cell = ws['B2']

### Create Named Style
namedstyle = NamedStyle(name="namedstyle")

### Copy Styles
namedstyle.font = copy(style_cell.font)
namedstyle.alignment = copy(style_cell.alignment)
namedstyle.border = copy(style_cell.border)
namedstyle.fill = copy(style_cell.fill)

namedstyle.number_format = style_cell.number_format

### Register style with the workbook:
wb.add_named_style(namedstyle)

### Add a value to cell 'B4' and apply style
ws['B4'].value = 36194
ws['B4'].style = namedstyle

wb.save("foo_out.xlsx")
```

The style is also available in the 'Styles' section of the Excel toolbar.

[image: B2 style applied to B4]